# Why does Azure Cosmos DB take so long to delete?

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

When removing a large resource group, the azure cosmos db is always by far the longest service to remove. When it comes to deployment, Redis usually takes the cake. I'm curious as to why my DocDB takes around 10 minutes to bring down. Any Ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it is a issue of Azure Cosmos DB itself, I try to delete a cosmos db on my side and check it in the **Activity log**, it takes me almost **20** minutes to complete it.

[image]

It may related to its feature, like global distribution, etc. If you want to improve it of Azure Cosmos DB, I recommend you to post your idea in the [feedback](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/263030-azure-cosmos-db).

Comment: I see the same behavior while deploying cosmos db (sql api). It took ~20 min.